# Como diferençar Conjunção/Advérbio (como) x Verbo (comer)

Tags: verbos, vírgula, conjunções

Recentemente, ao navegar nos *stories* do Instagram, deparei-me com a seguinte frase:

> Às vezes, tenho vontade de comentar **"estás linda, como sempre"**, mas — devido à discrição — comento apenas **estás linda como sempre**.

Sei que o termo *"como"* pode ser usado como advérbio de comparação; conjunção causal, comparativa e conformativa; e verbo.

**Minha dúvida é:** O termo *como* precedido de vírgula, no contexto apresentado, pode ser interpretado como verbo *comer* (sentido pejorativo)?

Sei que a conjunção *como*, quando introduz uma enumeração, pode ser precedida de vírgula (não parece ser o caso), por exemplo:

> Elas gostam de (vários) artistas, *como* (por exemplo) Tom Jobim, Gilberto Gil e Caetano Veloso. <sup>[fonte](https://gramaticaonline.com.br/a-virgula-antes-de-como/)</sup>

Comment: Ninguém leria aí o verbo _comer_. Sendo o verbo comer, a frase seria agramatical porque não é possível vislumbrar aí um objeto direto para _comer_. Além de que pediria um ponto final ou ponto e vírgula: as orações seriam completamente independentes.

Comment: @Artefacto de fato, o ponto e vírgula parece ser a pontuação correta para mudar o sentido da frase, apesar da vírgula também ser utilizada para separar orações independentes. Quanto ao objeto direto, ele não poderia está implícito, tal qual ocorre com o sujeito? Ao ler a frase, vejo uma ambiguidade. Um outro exemplo é: “— Como você está?” / “— Não (vou) como você, mas gostaria”. Obviamente dá para entender a frase, porém há uma ambiguidade.

Comment: Para que o objeto direto pudesse estar implícito (ou _comer_ estivesse a ser usado em sentido absoluto, tipo _eu como muito_), seriam precisos elementos contextuais muito fortes. E mesmo assim não me ocorre nada que legitimasse uma interpretação de _como_ como forma de _comer_. O facto de os sujeitos não estarem explícitos também impede que a frase passe um contraste _tu_ / _eu_ (tipo _tu estás linda, mas eu não, porque como muito_)

Comment: Na língua falada, dependendo do olhar, intonação, sorriso malicioso, etc., uma mulher bonita certamente vai interpretar o "como sempre" como "estou sempre disposto a ter relações carnais com você".

Comment: @Centaurus Com olhar/intonação/sorriso/etc. certos, a frase "vou fazer sopa de cenoura" poderia ser interpretada da mesma forma... O conteúdo da frase é basicamente irrelevante.

Comment: Francamente, o verbo comer para denotar as relações carnais, teria de estar em outra forma.

Comment: @Artefacto    Convenhamos que "como sempre" presta-se bem mais à ambiguidade do que "vou fazer sopa de cenoura".  Este dependerá muito mais da intonação pouco sutil e do "olhar de garfo-e-faca", do que o primeiro.

Comment: @Lambie Quando nós, homens, queremos transmitir um comentário ambíguo, em que um dos significados seja vulgar e de conteúdo sexual, é "um vale tudo" em termos de transgressão às normas linguísticas. Por isso, o "como sempre".

Comment: No Rio de Janeiro é comum, quando passa uma linda mulher, dois homens comentarem:   a. Linda !   b. Como sempre.  E então é motivo de risos.  Existem dezenas de frases-feitas desse tipo.

Comment: @Centaurus Sou mulher, fui criada no Rio. Queqcê acha? Uma coisa é um vale tudo  linguístico, mas existe também o fato de falar com certa "lógica" que até o zé povinho sabe, né? Mas deixisso prá lá....

Comment: Acredito que a ideia da frase seja criar, propositalmente, uma ambiguidade (ou indireta, talvez), por isso torna alguns termos implícitos. Na língua falada, é bem comum devido à ambiguidade ou à cacofonia, por exemplo: 1) `Fulano tem galinha e a mãe(;) dele(,) é uma vaca também.` (ambígua — dependendo da pontuação); 2) `Tem Coca aí na geladeira` (cacofonia, ouve-se *cocaína*); 3) `Ninguém aguenta mais a vaca da minha sogra` (ambígua). A dúvida postada é se a pontuação (seja vírgula ou ponto e vírgula) pode alterar o termo *como* para um verbo (em vez de advérbio) e porquê.

Comment: Um exemplo semelhante ao "como sempre"  é o "Você vai sair conosco amanhã?   Se der pra mim eu vou." com o sentido principal de "se der pra eu ir, eu vou", mas também com duplo sentido.

Comment: O político brasileiro José Serra foi alvo de muitas piadas devido ao uso de "como", e o duplo sentido que pode gerar. Se curioso, pode buscar na internet.

Answer (score 1):

O uso da palavra "comer" no sentido de prática de ato sexual ativamente é disseminado, e portanto o uso do verbo "comer" deve ser utilizado com muito cuidado pelo não nativo.

A diferenciação se dá somente pelo contexto.

A frase:

```
Joana está linda, como todos os dias.
```

Somente se diferencia de:

```
Hoje comi cenoura, como todos os dias.
```

devido ao contexto.
Do ponto de vista técnico, não existe uma forma ortográfica / lexográfica de diferenciar estes casos, inclusive na frase da cenoura existe uma ambiguidade.
Deve-se tomar o cuidado de não utilizar a conjunção/advérbio "como" em frases em que se possa atribuir significado indevido, ou seja, quando houver na frase a presença de pessoas ou animais que poderiam ser objeto de ato sexual.

Esta ambiguidade é frequentemente explorada em piadas e trocadilhos entre amigos, ao se cumprimentarem, explorando esta questão, como por exemplo:

```
- Como vai, meu amigão?
- Não tão bem **como você**. Mas bem que gostaria!
```

Esta brincadeira entre amigos explora a questão da ambiguidade semântica, e devemos tomar cuidado com o uso destas palavras para evitarmos gafes. Como regra geral, é recomendado ao estrangeiro evitar o uso da expressão "como você".